# Getting the IP Address of a Remote Socket Endpoint

Tags: c#, sockets, endpoints

How do I determine the remote IP Address of a connected socket?

I have a RemoteEndPoint object I can access and well as its AddressFamily member.

How do I utilize these to find the ip address?

Thanks!

Currently trying

```
IPAddress.Parse( testSocket.Address.Address.ToString() ).ToString();
```

and getting 1.0.0.127 instead of 127.0.0.1 for localhost end points. Is this normal?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx

You can then call the IPEndPoint..::.Address method to retrieve the remote IPAddress, and the IPEndPoint..::.Port method to retrieve the remote port number.

More from the link (fixed up alot heh):

```
Socket s;
        
IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = s.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
IPEndPoint localIpEndPoint = s.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

if (remoteIpEndPoint != null)
{
    // Using the RemoteEndPoint property.
    Console.WriteLine("I am connected to " + remoteIpEndPoint.Address + " on port number " + remoteIpEndPoint.Port);
}

if (localIpEndPoint != null)
{
    // Using the LocalEndPoint property.
    Console.WriteLine("My local IpAddress is " + localIpEndPoint.Address + " connected on port number " + localIpEndPoint.Port);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string ip = ((IPEndPoint)(testsocket.RemoteEndPoint)).Address.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

RemoteEndPoint is a property, its type is [System.Net.EndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.endpoint.aspx) which inherits from [System.Net.IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx).

If you take a look at IPEndPoint's [members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint_members.aspx), you'll see that there's an `Address` property.

Comment: All I see available for RemoteEndPoint's members is AddressFamily. How do I gain access to Address?

Comment: ((System.Net.IPEndPoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address

Comment: Thank you! :)
I am trying
 string remoteIP = IPAddress.Parse( testSocket.Address.Address.ToString() ).ToString();
and getting "1.0.0.127" instead of "127.0.0.1" for localhost connections. Is this normal?

Comment: Actually IPEndPoint inherits from EndPoint. The cast suggested may fail at run time.

Answer (score -2):

I've made this code in VB.NET but you can translate.
Well pretend you have the variable **Client** as a **TcpClient**

```
Dim ClientRemoteIP As String = Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.Remove(Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.IndexOf(":"))
```

Hope it helps! Cheers.

Comment: You don't have to do all those string functions.  It is much faster to just cast to  IPEndPoint  -    DirectCast(Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address