# C# TCP socket connection, output IP address

Tags: c#, parsing, tcp, ip-address

I brought the question up a few days back on how to output/parse an IP address. Some suggestions were provided, and after a couple days of hitting my head against the wall, attempting the different suggestions, I'm no further. I'm sure the suggestions were OK, but the method in which I was trying to utilize them is where I failed.

So...I'd like to start from just a basic perspective.

```
  {
        BaseClient bc = null;
        try
        {
            if (m_TCP_Socket == null)
            {
                Console.Write("Client disconnected");
            }
            else
            {   

                //Console.WriteLine("New TCP connection made.");

                bc = GetNewClient();
                bc.Socket = m_TCP_Socket.EndAccept(ar);
                lock (m_clients)
                    m_clients.Add(bc);

                bc.OnConnect();
                bc.BeginReceive();
            }
}
```

}

I would like for it to simply console out, "New TCP Connection made. IP:###.###.###.###. If you respond, please don't be to presumptuous about what I may know, and not know, as I am student, and trying to learn things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1904184/1780038

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the manual. [`Socket.EndAccept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endaccept.aspx) returns a [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), from which you can read the [`RemoteEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx) property which will be an [`IPEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx), which has an [`Address`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.address.aspx) property. I think you're looking for the latter.