# Socket property that returns IP address/Port

Tags: vb.net, sockets, ip-address

I am trying to get a `String` representation of the `IP Address` and `Port` that my `Socket` has been initialized with. I am using this data to print in a message box for the user if an error occurs.

Using the `WinSock` control in VB6 the following code was used:

```
"Could not open TCP Connection to " & frmMain.winSock1.RemoteHost & ":" 
          & frmMain.winSock1.RemotePort
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: You would be better to show the VB.NET code instead of the VB6 so we can see how it is being initalised etc.

Comment: @MattWilko I believe OP is just showing what worked in VB6 in the past, and is looking for an approximation to that.

Comment: This question has more or less been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904160/getting-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-socket-endpoint

Comment: @Verdolino the link you provided is for C#, not vb.net.

Comment: It's really a simple question about System.Net.Sockets.Socket. As seen in the accepted answer, it is a .Net language agnostic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Socket` does not know the remote IP/Port until it actually connects to the server. You have to provide a destination to its [`Connect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method first. If `Connect()` fails, you have to know the destination you provided so you can report it, you cannot query the `Socket` for it.  If you connect asynchronously, you will have to remember that destination somewhere so you can retrieve it when needed.

However, if `Connect()` succeeds, you can query the [`RemoteEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the actual IP/Port that the `Socket` connected to.  This is particularly useful when connecting to a hostname, to discover what IP address the hostname resolved to.