# C# Get client information before server accept

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I search over the internet without any luck.
What im trying to do is get the client ip address that is attempting to connect to remote server before connecting the client, to prevent unauthorised access to the server.

Im using tcp protocol and .net winforma, linux not allowed to be authorised.
Is it possible? If it is, how would i do that

I need to be able to check if the client is authorized to access the server before the server connect him

Comment: Hi there! There is a lot of questions: What is your protocol? TCP? UDP? HTTP? What are your framework? MVC? WebAPI? ASP.Net or .Net Core? What have you try so far? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904184/466227

Comment: Im using tcp protocol and using .net winforms. Im not allowed to use linux systems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the IP Address of a Remote Socket Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904160/getting-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-socket-endpoint)

Comment: Its not a dumpliced.. Those links are after the client HAS Connected. I need to get address before he is connected

Comment: Why not just configure your firewall? Why are you making this an *application* task? If you're going to make it an application task, you *should* do it after the connection is established, to avoid easy DOS attacks.